# How to use Navigator 2.0 with Page Controller in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

I'm developing a flutter application where if the user is logged in, he'll see a page with 5 different pages (using Page Controller). I'm trying to use flutter navigator to kind of develop the navigation for the app. This is what I'm trying to achieve: Let's say there are 5 pages on the landing page: a-page, b-page ,c-page, d-page, e-page. The user initially lands on the c-page, at this point, the path should be "/c-page" and whenever the user switches the page, the path should change accordingly. For instance, currently the path is "/c-page", if the user switches to the b-page, the path should be "b-page". So basically the b-page path should replace the c-page path in this case. I tried replacing the path but wasn't completely successful. How can I achieve this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you mean [PageController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController-class.html)? if so, it is used by a `PageView` widget so i am not clear what does it have to do with `Navigator` 2.0...

Comment: What I mean is, along with navigating the page to other screens in PageController, I want to give them a path as well (like "/a-page" and "/b-page"). The reason is, when I send notifications to people on the app, it wouldn't have a context. Let's say I have a messaging page and the button to the messaging page is placed on the a-page. When the user clicks on the notification, it's going to redirect them on the messaging page. What I want is, when the user clicks on the back button on the messaging page, they should be redirected to the a-page where the messaging button has been placed.

Comment: again, what does it have to do with Navigator 2.0? all what you say is how to animate to different pages of `PageView` widget (where you can directly use `PageController.jumpToPage` and `PageController.animateToPage` methods), but you do not mention any navigator stuff

Comment: Can I use navigator in this case? I have a question, if there are two pages, home page and profile page in the PageController. On the homepage, there's a messaging button and in the profile page, there is a settings button. When the user clicks on the messaging notification, how can I ensure that when the user clicks on the back button, he will be redirected to the Homepage where the messaging button is.

Comment: use `PageController.jumpToPage` or `PageController.animateToPage` methods

Comment: Alright, I'll try it. Thanks for helping :).